# When we migrated to Magento 2 we found that we were unable to edit configrable products price from Admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.6

When we migrated to Magento 2 we found that we were unable to edit configrable products from Admin.

I want to be able to change the price.

Please tell me how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: It's not an issue, basically configurable product price is used no where, so it cannot be editable only it's associative price will be used. Check the default magento before migration.
Thanks